cms Diafan: как работает модуль сравнения товаров
Не нахожу ответ в официальной документации. В коде выводится кнопка, которая должна добавлять товар в список сравнения, однако она ничего не делает. Файлы из дефолтного шаблона, так что не могу понять в чем дело. Есть у кого-то информация, как должно работать сравнение товаров в диафане?
